# SQL Server Agent start and stop script which can be run by normal user not system admin

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created couple of jobs in SQL Server Agent. Now I need to deploy these jobs on client machines. Client SQL Servers don't have system admin login.

What I want to do is to let normal SQL login (not system admin) users run the start and stop SQL Agent Service script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure with [`execute as owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx).  That procedure will run as system admin and can start and stop jobs with [`sp_start_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).

You can then give normal users `execute` rights on the stored procedure.  That will allow them to start/stop jobs.